# oAuth2.0 authentication with crm365

Tags: dynamics-crm-365

I try to write console app with crm service and I get this error:

> Unable to connect to CRM: An error occurred when processing the
> security tokens in the message:You are using Ws-Tust authentication
> which has been deprecated and no longer supported in your environment.
> Please use oAuth2.0 authentication.

how I can to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this connection string:

```
"AuthType=OAuth;
 Username=jsmith;
 Password=passcode;
 Url=https://xxx.crm4.dynamics.com;
 AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d;
 RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;
 TokenCacheStorePath=c:\MyTokenCache;
 LoginPrompt=Auto"
```

Where **Username** is your CRM login and **Password** is your password accordingly.
**Url** is the link to your crm instance.

**AppId** and **RedirectUri** should be yours Ids from AzureAD but I've took them at official documantation page [Use connection strings in XRM tooling to connect to Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (on-premises)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect#oauth-using-named-account-in-dynamics-365-customer-engagement-on-premises-with-ux-to-prompt-for-authentication) and it worked for me :-).

Comment: I had the same error and still does not work after trying your connection string format; still getting the error "An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message:You are using Ws-Trust authentication which has been deprecated and no longer supported in your environment. Please use OAuth2.0 authentication."